# Flask app on non-root url of website with Apache2

Tags: flask, apache2, hosting, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a Flask app that I would like to host on a subdomain / non-root url of our lab website. For example, I want mylab.com/portal to lead to the flask app. I followed numerous guides but I keep getting a 404 error.

My Directory structure:

```
/var/www/
    -html/
         -Stuff for mylab.com
    -FlaskApp/
         -FlaskApp.wsgi
         -FlaskApp/
              -__init__.py
              -static/
              -templates/
              -...
```

FlaskApp.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

activate_this = '/home/cogsci-cnddcollab/FlaskApp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/FlaskApp')

from FlaskApp import app as application
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
WSGIRestrictStdout Off
WSGIScriptReloading On

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName mylab.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://mylab.com/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>



    ## FlaskApp
    WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp_wsgi user=cogsci-cnddcollab group="domain users" threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /portal /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp_wsgi
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /portal/static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /portal/templates /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templates
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templates>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I restart the apache2 service and go to mylab.com/portal, I am hit with a 404 error. I have added `APPLICATION_ROOT=/portal` to my config.py file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining your routes? The routes in your Python code should not include ``/portal`` in them.

Comment: Also, does your Apache config have a virtual host for 443 port. The ``Redirect`` you have means that any request would be routed over to the 443 port and all your config in the 80 port virtual host for mod_wsgi would be ignored.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am not including `/portal` in any of my routes so I don't think that is the issue. Our `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory does have a `default-ssl.conf` file with a virtualhost for port 443 that I did not see before.  I think you may have just solved my problem!